# How to open google search keyboard using intent (Android TV)?

Tags: android-intent, google-search, android-tv

I want to open Google keyboard search layout on my Android TV app, as it is provided by the default android launcher. Shown in the picture given below.

[image]

On clicking this button it opens the page given below.

[image]

I want to know what are the intent parameters to open this activity on Android TV via my app. I also get this log in my system logcat when I click this button.

```
system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.ASSIST flg=0x10a00000 cmp=com.google.android.katniss/.search.KeyboardSearchActivity (has extras)} from uid 10028
```

PS: My app is user app and doesn't have any root privileges.

**Edit 1:**

After using the following intent

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.katniss", "com.google.android.katniss.search.KeyboardSearchActivity"));
```

I get this error

```
W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.google.android.katniss/.search.KeyboardSearchActivity } from ProcessRecord{4ff6631 14881:com.basic.android.basiclauncher/u0a55} (pid=14881, uid=10055) not exported from uid 10028
E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.google.android.katniss/.search.KeyboardSearchActivity } from ProcessRecord{4ff6631 14881:com.basic.android.basiclauncher/u0a55} (pid=14881, uid=10055) not exported from uid 10028
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not exported`
So in `AndroidManifest.xml` this activity set `android:exported="false"`
So that only root privileges can start this.

Comment: If a comment can answer a question try posting a comment instead of an answer.
See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So there is no way to access it without root.

Answer (score 0):

Actually non exported activities can't be opened in normal scenarios this way.

Fortunately there is a specific intent with which you can open katniss with keyboard:

```kotlin
Intent(Intent.ACTION_ASSIST)
    //add this extra for keyboard mode, without it will trigger voice search
    .apply { putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ASSIST_INPUT_HINT_KEYBOARD, true) }
    .run { context.startActivity(this) }
```

It also would be nice to check if there is an Activity which can handle this intent. It may happen on some devices that katniss is not installed or there is multiple apps handling this intent.